# Получение полного пути к файлу

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть код:

```
if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    filename = this.FileUpload1.FileName;
    path = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
}
```

По идее, после компиляции в `path` должен храниться полный путь к файлу, но вместо `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\имя_файла`, даже если файл хранится на рабочем столе, то путь будет `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`.

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileName - это имя файла на клиентской машине. Оно вообще ничего не значит на серверной стороне.

Судя по комментам, имя файла вам нужно чтобы получить полный путь к нему, прочитать его содержимое и записать в базу данных. На самом деле файл к этому моменту уже был открыт, прочитан с диска браузером, отправлен из браузера на сервер. И для записи в базу данных вам не нужно его открывать и читать.

Вся схема работает примерно так:

1. Пользователь выбирает файл в диалоге браузера
2. Браузер целиком читает файл и отправляет его **содержимое** и имя на сервер.
3. Сервер получает и содержимое и имя от браузера, и отдает их вам в виде свойств `FileUpload`.

Имя в этом случае - простро строчка, а не реальное имя файла на сервере. А содержимое - просто массив байт.

Вам достаточно взять готовое содержимое файла из `FileUpload1.FileBytes` и записать его в базу. Пытаться открыть файл по имени бессмысленно - потому что имя файла - это просто строчка, которая вообще ничего не значит на стороне сервера.

Comment: Вот человеческое вам спасибо ! Только ваше решение моей проблемы открывает для меня новую проблему :) как мне теперь вытянуть из mp3 файла (автора, название и прочее) если на севере файл будет представлен в бинарном коде.

Comment: @kxxko все файлы всегда представлены в бинарном коде. Если вам нужен именно файл на диске - сохраните его через `File.WriteAllBytes` в какую-то папку на сервере, задав полный путь. Но вообще вопрос - а как вы собирались вытягивать из mp3 ту же информацию, считая что это просто файл на диске?

Comment: Есть библиотека для таких нужд полезная под названием TagLib. Она opensource, так что все легально =) Там есть метод var audioFile = TagLib.File.Create() - где в параметрах я должен указать путь к фалу, а потом уже можно работать с этим файлом и достать от туда все что угодно.

Comment: в принципе можно сохранить файл выбранный в базу и сохранить в выбранную папку, быстренько от туда достать нужные данные и удалить файл =)

Comment: Не говорите глупостей. У `TagLib#` есть такой интерфейс как `IFileAbstraction`. Если его реализовать, то можно будет передать его в метод `File.Create` вместо имени файла.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что ASP.NET сайт - это не exe-файл. Сайт запускается с помощью ве-сервера (IIS Express в вашем случае), и поэтому в качестве пути вы получаете корневую папку IIS'а.

Попробуйте так:

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: Теперь возвращает путь, где хранится проект + название файла =)

Comment: файл, который вам нужен, лежит на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: файл лежит на клиенте. я беру путь к файлу, что бы записать его в БД.

Comment: а зачем вам вообще на сервере нужен путь с клиента? Сервер не может быть уверенным, что на клиенте этот адрес не поменяется, ведь сервер клиента не контролирует

Comment: мне нужно реализовать все как в C# это делает OpenFileDialog. Выбрать файл (а из файла уже взять путь). И не важно, что не контролирует, потому что на момент добавления файла в БД путь его не будет меняться. Может я и ошибаюсь, я нуб =)

Comment: @kxxko А разве FileName сам не возвращает сразу путь? зачем еще GetFullPath?

Comment: @kxxko Сервер ничего не знает о клиентских путях, поэтому вы не можете получить полный путь к файлу на клиенте. Вы можете только знать имя файла и получить содержимое этого файла (то есть загрузить его на сервер)

Comment: @DreamChild а как мне тогда можно взять путь файла ? Мои методы зависят от пути к файлу, а на сервер не желательно загружать ничего.

Comment: @kxxko я не знаю, что вы задумали, но явно что-то неправильное. Сервер знать ничего не знает про клиентские файлы. Они находятся на других компьютерах (это только когда вы разрабатываете свое приложение, клиент и сервер находятся на вашей машине, но по факту это практически единственный такой случай) Сервер не может из соображений безопасности иметь доступ к файловой системе клиентса. Более того,серверу совершенно неправильно полагаться на состояние клиента, в частности, на какие-то его файлы, поэтому то, что вы делаете - неправильно и в такой постановке этот вопрос правильного ответа не имеет

Comment: @DreamChild да быть того не может, что бы нельзя было в ASP взять путь из выбранного файла =(

Comment: @DreamChild дело в том, что я должен реализовать метод, который считывает файл (из пути к файлу).

Comment: @DreamChild смотрел примеры на StackOverFlow eng, точно такой же код как у меня но у ребята работает ! а у меня нет

Comment: @kxxko ради бога, можете не верить. Но нормальными средствами этого сделать нельзя из соображений безопасности.

Comment: @DreamChild уже прочитал статью на эту тему. действительно нельзя. спасибо за ответ, но все же как мне стоит сделать правильно ?

Comment: вы, вероятно, неправильно понимаете принципы взаимодействия клиента и сервера раз хотите чего-то подобного

Comment: да, не понимаю. я впервые делаю приложение на asp.

Comment: в таком случае вам имеет смысл изучить основы прежде чем писать код